# Convert ggraph to interative plot with plotyly or Network3D

Tags: r, plotly, interactive, force-layout, ggraph

I was looking for an example or tutorial to convert a `ggraph` object to an iterative force network.

First I tried to convert to `plotly` object using `plotly::ggplotly` function. But seems the `plotly` don't deal nicely with this kind of conversion and miss the edges.

But I find the `network3D`, I can convert an `igraph` object to a `network3D` object, but it is not what I wanted. And this package has too verbose functions. Anyway, there is no function to convert from `ggraph` object.

So, my question is really basic but... Do you know any method to crate an interactive `ggraph` network?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [ggiraph](https://davidgohel.github.io/ggiraph/index.html) package, it works with ggraph as you can see in the example [here](https://davidgohel.github.io/ggiraph/articles/offcran/examples.html) (bottom of the page).

For future reference (if the above link may die), here's the example of ggiraph (not my code):

```
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)
library(ggiraph)

actors <- data.frame(
  name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David", "Esmeralda"),
  age = c(48,33,45,34,21),
  gender = c("F","M","F","M","F")
)
relations <- data.frame(
  from = c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David", "David", "Esmeralda"),
  to = c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice"),
  same.dept = c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),
  friendship = c(4,5,5,2,1,1),
  advice = c(4,5,5,4,2,3)
)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations,
       directed = TRUE, vertices = actors)

z <- ggraph(g, layout = 'linear', circular = TRUE) +
  geom_edge_arc(color = "red", edge_width = .2) +
  geom_point_interactive(size = 5,
    mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, data_id = gender,
                  tooltip = paste0(name, ": ", age, "y.o."))
  ) + theme_graph()

girafe(ggobj = z, width_svg = 5, height_svg = 5,
       options = list(opts_sizing(rescale = FALSE)))
```

It seems plotly does not support ggraph yet, but you can track the progress [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/566).